# Hit an EC2 instance in another account from an AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-lambda, aws-security-group

We have a Lambda function in an account and we would like to access an EC2 instance (via HTTP) in another VPC which has a public IP attached. I was wondering what would be the best way to perform this communication. I am new to Lambda and I just got to know of the VPC lambdas. Which CIDRs do I need to open on the Security Group on the EC2 instance? Can I have a specific set of public IPs being picked in the source VPC - this way I can whitelist that range in the SG?

Does VPC peering seem like an overhead for this case or the only possible solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "access an EC2 instance"? Do you mean via HTTP, SSH or something else? Are you okay if the traffic goes via a public IP address and the Internet, or do you need to keep the traffic private within VPCs?

Comment: Either case is fine in terms of traffic going or not going to the Internet. By Access, I meant HTTP request.

Comment: Is the EC2 instance currently "wide open" on HTTP, or do you wish to limit access to only the Lambda function?

Comment: We would want to limit the access to smaller CIDR than open to all. So, yes, only Lambda-based access would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all Depends on your requirements.However, Peering those VPCs is the best way to have the traffic remaining in your trusted Private Subnets which are located in the Internal Trust Boundaries which satisfies Security best practices (Threat/Security Models and Cloud/Network Architecture).

If there is an enterprise policy with strict rules that communication shall not be routed via DMZ/Public Internet and is a must to keep things within the Trusted Boundary of Internal Routes, I don't see any other choice but to go with the VPC peering : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/peer-with-vpc-in-another-account.html

However, if requirements are less strict and you can use Public Internet to forward your Traffic out via DMZ, it is possible to achieve this with out sacrificing too much of Security (assuming that your EC2 with public IP on other account is providing service over SSL/TLS where your lambda can communicate with it over an Encrypted Communication Channel while validating the EC2's certificate).

This could be achieved by having Lambda associated with an Internal Subnet of your VPC to talk to the EC2 of other account with Public IP. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html

Yes, You still can have your Lambda remaining inside the Internal Subnet. But you need a NAT GATEWAY and update the Routing Table for Lambda's Internal Subnet to point to the NAT GATEWAY (which should be assigned with an EIP) i.e. it will subsequently point to your INTERNET GATEWAY. By this you will make sure that your LAMBDA which, located in your private subnet of VPC can talk with outside i.e. with the EC2 instance, located in another account's with a Public IP. Therefore you can whitelist one IP in the SecurityGroups of your EC2 in Other Account which is the EIP of your NATGATEWAY which Lambda or any other Internal Components in that subnet will use to find their way out to the Internet.

Comment: What would be the biggest concern with VPC peering? Two I can think of are: 1) Private IP CIDR management. 2) Blast radius if our VPC gets compromised. Anything else?

Comment: It all depends on context, your assets in VPCs, Risk posture and Controls.If you have a radius in one and you are peering with a 3rd Partie's VPC which you have no trust & control on then its a concern. Such discussions can go to infinity: what if then but what if then scenarios.If both Accounts and VPCs are owned by same Organization? Same Department? Same Team? Least Privilege/Segregation & Isolation needs.would  u create a New VPC isolated from Radius access and then peeri?or no just having one NAT Gateway and add only 1IP in SG route to internet instead of CIDR Block has a less risk for u.

Comment: Thank you! I guess one additional use-case we have is that we would prefer VPC A to connect to VPC B (and get the response back) but VPC B cannot initiate a connection to VPC A and access its resources. Is it possible with the peering?

Comment: I think the answer would be NACL. I suggest if you divide your VPC A in to Smaller Managable Subnet and then Apply NACL Inboud/Outbound Rules there you can let Outbound traffic be flown to Destination VPC B but for inbound Deny the CIDR block of VPC B.   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html